# Outlook startup macro execution results are different from manually initiated copy

Tags: vba, outlook, startup

Every weekday morning I would like to see the content of a specific subfolder in my personal profile right after starting Outlook.

I have an Outlook macro that when fired manually the folder is activated, content (all mails) is shown.

I copied the macro to ThisOutlookSession and restarted Outlook.
The macro starts and the folder *is* activated.
*Nothing* is shown (it is not empty for sure).

*Nothing* is shown in *any* folders having run the macro this way. Content of any folder is shown *for a second* when I switch from one folder to another. The content is there but won't show *permanently*.

```vb
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Activate_SubFolder
End Sub
    
Sub Activate_SubFolder()
    
    Dim myfolder As Folder
    
    Set myfolder = Session.Folders("myname@mycompany.com").Folders("Subfolder1").Folders("Subfolder2")
    
    Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = myfolder
    
    Set myfolder = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Forget to mention that when I run the macro manually, content of this specific folder as well as other folders is permanently shown. :-O

Comment: Check the view to see if there is a filter.

Comment: @niton, if you mean Outlook/View/View Settings/Filter..., then no, there is no filter set (it is "off").